# jQuery - hide div and content

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to hide my div content using jQuery. This is my code:

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="id_category">Category</label><div class="col-md-9"><select class="form-          control" id="id_category" name="category" title="" required>
 <option value="">---------</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">Zdrowie i uroda</option>
 <option value="3">Komputery</option>
 <option value="4">Domy i mieszkania</option>
 <option value="5">Państwa, miasta, regiony</option>
 </select></div></div>
```

I don't know how can I select this whole div and hide it. I have multiple similar divs in my page. They differ in id (there is id_category, another is id_subcategory). Is it possible to hide only div that contains id_category?

For testing i tried:

```
$(".form-group.col-md-3.control-label").hide();
```

but it doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You want to hide all so you just need to hide the parent of everything.

```js
$(".form-group").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group"><label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="id_category">Category</label><div class="col-md-9"><select class="form-          control" id="id_category" name="category" title="" required>
 <option value="">---------</option>
 <option value="2" selected="selected">Zdrowie i uroda</option>
 <option value="3">Komputery</option>
 <option value="4">Domy i mieszkania</option>
 <option value="5">Państwa, miasta, regiony</option>
 </select></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`label` is a child element of the div with class `.form-group`, so your selector has to be different:

```
$(".form-group .col-md-3.control-label").hide();
```

(Note the added space)

Answer (score 0):

You should find a child of div with uniqe attribute value and then use [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method.

```js
$('#id_category').closest('.form-group').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="id_category">Category</label>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <select class="form-          control" id="id_category" name="category" title="" required>
      <option value="">---------</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">Zdrowie i uroda</option>
      <option value="3">Komputery</option>
      <option value="4">Domy i mieszkania</option>
      <option value="5">Państwa, miasta, regiony</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$('.form-group').hide()`

You are not selecting the correct element in your solution.

`$(".form-group.col-md-3.control-label")` selects the child label element, not the parent

See Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/bh0qy28t/

Comment: It works here but in my website it doesn't. I realized that when I use class as selector it doesn't work. Only id as selector works. It is really strange.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at my chrome dev tools and take proper selector from here. Here is correct solution:

```
$("div > fieldset > div.form-row.field-category1").hide();
```

Comment: if that is the solution, where is element `div` with `.field-category1` class in your question?